# what does forward slash in regex means

Tags: regex

I have the following regular expression which I am analyzing from last few days.

```
/8c/4!n1!x4!n
```

Can anyone tell what does the forward slash mean in this regex.

Comment: Why do you think it means anything? Is it not matching as expected?

Comment: which language are you using..

Comment: Perhaps only `/8c/` is the actual regex, and the rest is some other PERL argument (as in `s/(left){3}/right/g`)

Comment: Looks almost like `sed`.

Answer (score 6):

Without any context such as a particular programming language's conventions, a forward slash in a regex has no special meaning; it simply matches a literal forward slash.

In some languages, such as `sed`, Awk, Perl, and PHP, slashes are used around regular expressions in some contexts.

```
/foo/n
```

This `sed` script, for example, selects the `n` (next line) action if the current pattern space contains text which matches the regular expression `foo`. As you can see, the slashes are used to bracket the regular expression.

As an aside, in `sed` and Perl (and PHP?) the slash character is simply the default, and you can switch to a different nonalphabetic delimiter if you like.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a regex, although it is similar; it is a SWIFT financial message field format definition.

See for example page 8 of https://www2.swift.com/uhbonline/books/public/en_uk/stdsdkug_20090925/stds_dev_kit_user_guide.pdf

A rough translation might be literal character "/", followed by up to 8 alphabetic chars, followed by a "/", then exactly 4 numeric, exactly 1 alphanumeric, and exactly 4 numeric chars. The "!" denotes "Exactly".